# Getting angular-socket-io working with Grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I'm having problems to get socket.io working with my project that uses Grunt. I'm currently using angular-socket-io via bower. So here are things that I have done this far:

1) Installed angular-socket-io and socket.io-client via bower

2) Imported following lines exactly into `index.html`

```
<script src="bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.min.js"></script>
```

3) Added 'btford.socket-io' into my app.js

```
angular.module('angularApp', [ 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'btford.socket-io'])
```

4) Made `Socket.js` file which is

```
app.factory('Socket', ['socketFactory', '$location',
    function(socketFactory, $location) {
        if($location.host() === "127.0.0.1") {
            return socketFactory({
                prefix: '',
                ioSocket: io.connect($location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + ':' + $location.port())
            });
        } else {
            return socketFactory({
                prefix: '',
                ioSocket: io.connect({path: '/node_modules/socket.io'})
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

Project structure:

```
Project
|
- node_modules
  |
  - socket.io
- src
  |
  - main
    |
    - webapp
      |
      - app
        |
        - bower_components
        - scripts
          |
          - controllers
          - services
          - app.js
          - Socket.js
        - styles
        - views
        - index.html
- bower.json
- Gruntfile.js
- server.js
```

But I get following error on every polling:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:9000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1448635105443-105 404 (Not Found)
```

What could be wrong? Is it possible to tell angular to import some specific modules of node? I have been searching solution for this from stackoverflow and also Googled it many days, but I haven't found any solution.

However I have found that when it tries to GET socket.io using that address it tries to get it from node_modules path. I have installed there just in case socket.io via npm.

I have also read the instructions of angular-socket-io at Github [angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io)

**EDIT***
I have tried to create `server.js` which includes following lines:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(9000, "127.0.0.1");

function handler (req, res) {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/src/main/webapp/app/index.html',
      function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          res.writeHead(500);
          return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
      });
    }

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('news', {message: 'hello world'});
    socket.on('my event', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

But it still say the same thing.

Comment: Try using io.on instead of io.sockets.on

Comment: @Gary: tried and didn't help.

Comment: The fact that the client is attempting to contact the server is good, as it means you most likely have the client setup properly.  Your issue looks to be on the server side.  Are you able to load the index.html?  Make sure your server is actually running.

Comment: @Gary: I'm using `grunt serve` to run my front-end. I have configured in `Gruntfile.js` that `server.js` file will be watched. I also did simple test, that I wrote this line `console.log("Testing");` in `server.js` and then run `grunt serve` command and it prints fine but of course not in browser console but instead in the Command Prompt, since I run my project in Windows environment with localhost. Regarding loading the index.html, at least I don't get 'Error loading index.html' message, so I assume I don't get error from that side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working. So here's the answer for anyone who is running Grunt as server using `grunt serve` or `grunt connect`.

First do all four steps that are done in question above.

Secondly when you use Grunt to run your server, you need to install and use npm package called [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) which will have `onCreateServer` function. This function will allow us to use socket.io with Grunt. This function is included with at least version 0.11.2 of `grunt-contrib-connect`. You need to load this package in your Gruntfile. If you haven't done so yet, then you can simply add following line to your `Gruntfile.js`

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect')`

Now that you have loaded that npm task you can now use `onCreateServer` function to use socket.io, like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        port: 8000,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        onCreateServer: function(server, connect, options) {
          var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
          // do something with socket
          io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
              io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
                  socket.emit('news', {message: 'hello world'});
                  socket.on('my event', function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                  })
              });
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Finally you can go to your controller and use your Socket factory you did on client side (in our case it is `Socket.js`). Here is example of controller:

```
angular.module('angularApp').controller('MyCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$resource', 'Socket', function($rootScope, $scope, $resource, Socket ){
    Socket.on('news', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        Socket.emit('my event', {my: 'data'});
    })
}]);
```

**TIP:** If you are using `livereload` in your `server.options` then you don't have to worry about it. You can use `livereload` with `socket.io`.