# How to add socket.io to my gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, socket.io, gruntjs

I have a Gruntfile.js generated automatically and would like to add socket.io (it client part is working). I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959887/getting-angular-socket-io-working-with-grunt) but, it is not working.

This is my Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.initConfig({

      connect: {
    options: {
      port: 9000,
      hostname: '0.0.0.0',
      livereload: 35729,
      onCreateServer: function(){
      var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
      console.log("new sever ----------------------------------------");
      }
    },
    livereload: {
      options: {
        open: true,
        middleware: function (connect) {
          return [
            connect.static('.tmp'),
            connect().use(
              '/bower_components',
              connect.static('./bower_components')
            ),
            connect().use(
              '/app/styles',
              connect.static('./app/styles')
            ),
            connect.static(appConfig.app)
          ];
        }
      }
    },
    test: {
      options: {
        port: 9001,
        middleware: function (connect) {
          return [
            connect.static('.tmp'),
            connect.static('test'),
            connect().use(
              '/bower_components',
              connect.static('./bower_components')
            ),
            connect.static(appConfig.app)
          ];
        }
      }
    },
    dist: {
      options: {
        open: true,
        base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

How can I introduce socket.io in this project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take socket.io client file from [socket.io](http://socket.io/download/) cdn, at this address https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js.

You don't have to take if from your running server.

Comment: thanks for you answer. But it is not necessary to attach it to my server like : `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);` like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959887/getting-angular-socket-io-working-with-grunt)